# Inheritance of the generated NSManagedObject

Tags: inheritance, nsmanagedobject

I have XCode auto-generated NSManagedObjects and my custom classes that inherit those auto-generated and add some additional methods and properties. e.g.

> MOUser: NSManagedObject - autogenerated
>
> User: MOUser - my custom class

If I fetch data using

```
[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:someFetchRequest error:&error];
```

I'm getting instance of *MOUser* type (what is expected). How can I make instance of my *User* class to be able to use added properties and methods?

Answer (score 1):

Core Data will always return classes that map to the entities in the data model.  If you need additional methods and/or properties that are not backed by model attributes, use a category instead of a subclass.